# How do I Ignore "dev" packages when using poetry to install pre-release package versions?

Tags: python, pypi, python-poetry

We have a local PyPi repository where we publish internal Python packages. I am working on a beta release package. In our PyPi repo, there are the following:

```
my-buildtools:
2.0.0b11
2.0.0b11.dev13+devdescriptor.ac8e44fd0
2.0.0b11.dev14+devdescriptor.00fed8321c
```

The two dev packages were published prior to the non-dev package. The first one is a beta *release* that I want to use in other projects. I am using poetry 1.1.4.

In my local environment, I call:
`poetry add --dev my-buildtools@2.0.0b11`

When I run that, I see:

`Installing my-buildtools (2.0.0b11.dev13+devdescriptor.ac8e44fd0)`

This results in my pyproject.toml file updating as so:

```
[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
my-buildtools = "2.0.0b11"
```

poetry.lock ends up with the following:

```
[[package]]
name = "my-buildtools"
version = "2.0.0b11.dev13+devdescriptor.ac8e44fd0"
description = "Build Tools Python 3 Edition"
category = "dev"
optional = false
python-versions = ">=3.6.2,<4.0.0"

[package.dependencies]
attrs = "19.1.0"
requests = ">=2.25.1,<3.0.0"

[package.source]
type = "legacy"
url = "https://<local-repo>"
reference = "mystuff"

sonos-buildtools = [
    {file = "my-buildtools-2.0.0b11.dev13+devdescriptor.ac8e44fd0.tar.gz", hash = "sha256:..."},
    {file = "my-buildtools-2.0.0b11.dev14+devdescriptor.00fed8321c.tar.gz", hash = "sha256:..."},
    {file = "my-buildtools-2.0.0b11.tar.gz", hash = "sha256:..."},
    {file = "my_buildtools-2.0.0b11-py3-none-any.whl", hash = "sha256:..."},
    {file = "my_buildtools-2.0.0b11.dev13+devdescriptor.ac8e44fd0-py3-none-any.whl", hash = "sha256:..."},
    {file = "my_buildtools-2.0.0b11.dev14+devdescriptor.00fed8321c-py3-none-any.whl", hash = "sha256:..."},
]
```

But I want it to install the 2.0.0b11 package, not the dev packages. Is there a way to tell poetry to ignore those `.devX` versions? Or do I need to remove those dev packages once the released one is available?

Answer (score 3):

Use the following format to specify what not to install (blacklist):

```
poetry install --without dev
```

Or specify what to install (whitelist)

```
poetry install --with main,docs
poetry install --only main,docs
```

More details at https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#install